# Cannot Convert Value Of Type String To Expected Element Type

Tags: xcode, swift3

I'm receiving this error in my `//Fill Objects` section. I cannot seem to find a solution for "Expected Element Type". I've only seen solutions for "Expected Argument Type". Not sure what the difference is or how to fix this. Never came across this error before.

```
    //User Profile Info

struct userObject {

    var profilePicture: UIImage
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var cityState: String
}

//Fill Objects

var userArray: [userObject] = ["profilePicture", "name", "description", "cityState"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this for declaring an array.

```
let userArray: NSArray = ["profilePicture", "name", "description", "cityState"]
```

Try this.